# Show identity of subgroup is same as identity of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $1_H$ and $1_G$ be the identities of $H$ and $G$, respectively. Show that $1_H=1_G$.

My attempt is: since we know that the identity of a group is unique, and hence $1_H=1_G$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: $1_H$ and $1_G$ are the identities of two different groups (albeit one is contained in the other), so the uniqueness of the identity of a group doesn't directly give that $1_G = 1_H$.

Comment: Hint:  $1_G h=h $ for all $h \in H$.

Comment: It does follow from the uniqueness of identity - not on $H$ but on $H \cup \{e_G\}$ - verify that it is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Working in $G$, we have $1_H1_H=1_H=1_H1_G$. The first equality follows from the fact that $1_H$ is the identity of $H$ and $H$ inherits its operation from $G$. The second follows from the fact that $1_G$ is the identity of $G$. Now premultiply by $1_H^{-1}$ to obtain the result.

Comment: The first line assumes $1_H$ is in $G$. Can we avoid making this assumption?

Comment: @IonSme $1_H$ is in $H$ which is a subset of $G$. Not only it is not an assumption, it is a necessary fact foisted upon us.

Comment: @EE18, is that part of the definition of groups or something? Who "foisted it upon us"?

Comment: So in other words, no element of a group can be an identity for itself aside from the identity of the whole group. Does this argument go further? Could you possibly have $1_Hh = h$ for all $h \in H \setminus \{1_H\}$ but $1_H \neq 1_G$?

Answer (score 9):

Knowing that the identity of a group is unique is not sufficient, since being an identity of $H$ does not directly imply being an identity of $G$. Also, previous answers have overlooked how the cancellation law depends on the identity element to work. For instance, by $1_H^{-1}$ do we mean an element from $G$ such that $1_H^{-1}1_H=1_G$? Or an element from $H$ such that $1_H^{-1}1_H=1_H$?

Let $1_H^{-1}$ be an element from $G$ such that $1_H^{-1}1_H=1_G$, for then $1_H=1_G1_H=1_H^{-1}1_H1_H=1_H^{-1}1_H=1_G$, which is what we wanted to show. (We only used the operation of $G$. The first equality follows from $1_G$ being the identity of $G$; the third equality follows from $1_H$ being the identity of $H$.)

Comment: The best answer ever! Thank you Lucas!

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**

Start with $1_{H}^2 = 1_{H}$.

Answer (score 5):

The identity of $H$ is an element of $G$ satisfying $x^2 = x$, and the only such element can be $1_G$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $h_1, h_2 \in H$ where $h_2$ is the inverse of $h_1$. Note that this is allowed since $H$ itself is a group. Then $h_1h_2 = 1_H$, but $h_1, h_2$ are both elements in $G$ as well, so $h_1h_2 = 1_G$. Therefore, $1_H = 1_G$.

Comment: This is not correct. If this were a proof it would also imply that if G were a halfgroup (with unity) and there it isnt true.

Answer (score 1):

Nice example in last comment, like such examples as they clarify the details.
I would add one more: for example, take operation $x*y=\max(x, y)$ and set $N$ of natural numbers (or some subset): it is closed, associative, comutative, have neutral (smallest element $1$). And if you exclude any subset containing current neutral, everything remain same just new minimum becomes new neutral. So, in monoid it can have subset with same operation but different neutral which is also monoid.
However, for groups (and quasigroups) is different, as from $1_G*1_H=1_H$ and $1_H*1_H=1_H$ (notation as in previous conments) it implies that equitation $X*1_H=1_H$ has $2$ solutions which is impossible in those structures:) This is at least the way I found easy to clarify to myself :)

Comment: Things like "in the last comment" should not be used. What you see, the order in which it appears, etc., need not be the same as the one others do, and it may change over time as well. I have no idea what you are refering to when you say "last comment".