# Proof of a Cayley graph result.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cayley-graphs

I am searching now for the most explicative and easy understand in this level (I am a second year student) proof of the following result:

A Cayley graph is connected iff S generates G

where G is a group and $S \subset G$ is a set of group of elements such that the identity $1_G \notin S$ .

Can someone post the proof or where do I can get it please :). Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Don't you think you should specify what $S$ and $G$ are?

Comment: well thanks for the advice I`ll post it :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't have a [subgroup not containing the identity of G](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291374/show-identity-of-subgroup-is-same-as-identity-of-group).

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CayleyGraph.html

Comment: You mean that S is a subset of the elements of G.

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: thanks for the edit, can you help me with the reference please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the cayley graph $\Gamma=(G, S)$ is connected, then there exists a directed path between any two vertices.  We want to show that the set $S$ generates $G$.  To generate $G$ means that we can write any element of $G$ as a product of elements in $S$.

Let $g$ be any element of $G$.  Then there is a path from $1$ (the identity in $G$) to $g$.  An edge in $\Gamma$ from $u$ to $v$ means that there is an element $s\in S$ so that $us=v$.  So the path from $1$ to $g$ corresponds to a sequence of steps (obtained by multiplication of elements in $S$).  $1s_{1}s_{2}...s_{n}=g$ is the path from $1$ to $g$.  Hence $g$ can be written as a product of elements in $S$, specifically $s_1 s_2 ... s_{n}$.

For the other direction.  Suppose that $S$ generates $G$.  We need to show that there is a directed path from any $u$ to any other $v$ in $\Gamma$.  Note that $u^{-1}v\in G$ so $u^{-1}v$ can be written as a product of elements in $S$, say $u^{-1}v = s_1 s_2 ... s_{n}$.  Then, that product describes the path from $u$ to $v$ in the Cayley digraph.  Specifically, $u (s_1 ... s_n)=u(u^{-1}v)=v$, a path from $u$ to $v$.

Comment: There is still some work to complete the proof, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thnks a lot for the help , but don't you have a reference to get the complete proof?

Comment: Is a textbook sufficient?  I can post the title/author when I get home.  It was in my intro abstract algebra textbook... (don't recall the title/author at the moment).

Comment: yes please :) and there  I can get the compete proof, thanks a lot :)

Comment: The text is "A first course in Abstract Algebra" by John Fraleigh... but it doesn't actually have the proof.  It just says that it is obviously true.  I will edit my previous post with a complete proof (it isn't hard).

Comment: Yes I appreciate that a lot :)

Comment: Hope that helps.  If you have additional questions, let me know.