# It is sufficient to find the inverse of an element in a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

I have a simple proposition about groups, but it is not obvious for me. (This question is motivated by the last answer in [Show identity of subgroup is same as identity of group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291374/show-identity-of-subgroup-is-same-as-identity-of-group) by *TheRealFakeNews*)

> Let $(G, \circ)$ and $(H, +)$ be groups with the identity elements $1_G$ and  $1_H$, respectively. (The operation $+$ is defined to be the operation $\circ$ restricted on the elements in $H$. In other words, for all $h_1, h_2 \in H$ we have $h_1 + h_2 = h_1 \circ h_2.$)
>
> Suppose that $(H, +)$ is a subgroup of $(G, \circ)$. Show that if $h_1, h_2 \in H$ and $h_1 + h_2 = 1_H$, then $h_1 \circ h_2 = 1_G$.

The proposition says that if $h_2$ is the inverse of $h_1$ in $(H, +)$, then also $h_2$ is the inverse of $h_1$ in $(G, \circ)$.

I know how to show that $1_H = 1_G$, from which the proposition is an easy consequence. But I want to prove the proposition, and use this to show that $1_H = 1_G$.

Since $(H, +)$ is a subgroup of $(G, \circ)$, we have $h_1, h_2, 1_H \in G$ and $h_1 \circ h_2 = 1_H$. Moreover, $1_G \circ 1_H = 1_H \circ 1_G = 1_H$ because $1_G$ is the identity in $(G, \circ)$. But I do now know to continue. Any suggestion please?

Comment: *NB:* "proof" and "prove" are different words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote the inverse of $h$ in $H$ by $h^{(-)}$, to possibly contrast with the inverse of $h$ in $G$, which is $h^{-1}$.

Let $h\in H$, and let $h^{(-)}$ be its inverse in $H$. Then you have that
$$h(hh^{(-)}) = h$$
in $H$, but also in $G$. That means that $hh^{(-)}$ is an element of $G$ that satisfies the equation $hx=h$ *in $G$*. The only element that satisfies that equation in $G$ is $1_G$, so $1_H = hh^{(-)} = 1_G$ and $h^{(-)} = h^{-1}$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.