# Proof check: Show that, for $n \geq 0$, $n\mathbb{Z} = \{nk : k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

**Proof.** For it to be a subgroup, the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}$ must be in $n\mathbb{Z}$. The identity element of $\mathbb{Z}$ under multiplication is 1. Suppose 1 is in $n\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $1 = nk$ for some $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. This means $k = 1/n$. But $1/n$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, therefore $n\frac{1}{n}$ is not an element of $n\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ under multiplication.

Would this be an appropriate proof?

Comment: First of all $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't even a group under multiplication. Second of all, for $n>0$, the set $n\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't contain multiplicative inverses.

Comment: riiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiight, that's where I kept butting my head. Thanks a lot! Feel free to add this as a response

Comment: I think either showing the identity element or the inverse element for nk are not in the subset. The inverse would be stronger as for some n (n=1) the identity element does exist, but the inverse element still does not.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under *addition*, but not multiplication, so we can't even really talk about subgroups here.

Comment: Welllllll.... if $n=0$, then $n\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$, which is a group under multiplication, just not a subgroup of anything in any relevant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remarked in the comments, $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a group under multiplication (for example, $2$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$). Therefore we can't even really talk about subgroups. What's more is, for $n>0$, the set $n\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't even form a group under multiplication at all for similar reasons.

The set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under addition however.

Comment: If $n=0$ then $n\Bbb Z=\{0\}$ $is$ a multiplicative group. The proposer incorrectly assumes that $1\in n\Bbb Z$ if $n\Bbb Z$ is a group. However, $0\in n\Bbb Z$ for any $n,$ so if $0\ne x\in n\Bbb Z$  then $n\Bbb Z$ is not a multiplicative group because there is no $y\in n\Bbb Z$ such that $0\cdot y=x$.... We $can$ talk about a subgroup of a ring or field. E,g. $\Bbb R^+$ is a multiplicative subgroup of $\Bbb R$. The "sub" means "subset".

Comment: That's why I specified $n>0$. And also, in order to be a subgroup, it needs to be a group under the *same* operation (as the group you're trying to say it's a subgroup of). So since $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a group under multiplication, it doesn't make sense to talk about "subgroups" under multiplication.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet is it not a condition for a subgroup to contain its parent's identity element?

Comment: @shintuku that's implied: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291374/show-identity-of-subgroup-is-same-as-identity-of-group